# Corrupted image in tkinter asksaveasfile

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to make a pop-up save qr code image window using asksaveasfile, but it gives me a corrupted image file.

[This is what happens if you open it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIVCR.png)

My code:

```
root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x350")

root.title("QR Code Generator")

label = Label(text="QR Code Generator", fg="black", font="NexaHeavy")

label.pack(pady=20)


link_entry = Entry()
link_entry.insert(0, 'Link')
link_entry.pack(pady=50)


name_entry = Entry()
name_entry.insert(0, 'QR Code name')
name_entry.pack(pady=50)

def savefile():
    asksaveasfile(defaultextension='*.jpg', filetypes=[
        ("All types", '.*'),
        ("JPG File", ".jpg")
    ])

# Generate QR Code
def make():
    qr_code = qrcode.make(link_entry.get())  
    qr_codename = (f"{name_entry.get()}.png")
    qr_code.save(qr_codename, savefile())
   

make_button = Button(text="Make QR Code", command=make)
make_button.pack(pady=1)
     


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to set `mode="wb"` in `asksaveasfile(...)`.

Comment: Its still corrupted

Comment: `savefile()` is useless in your code because the selected file is not used.

Comment: sadly, still doesnt work

Comment: It works for me even without `savefile()` since you have constructed the filename `qr_codename`.  As I said in previous comment, `savefile()` is useless. Actually the file you selected in `asksaveasfile()` will be an empty file.

Comment: exactly, i need to make asksaveasfile work because i want to user to choose in which directory he wants to save the file

Comment: Then why do you construct the filename `qr_codename`?

Comment: i forgot to remove it when added asksaveasfile function

Comment: but i dont really think it will help me fix the corrupted image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `asksaveasfile()` to select the output filename, you should not construct the filename using `qr_codename = (f"{name_entry.get()}.png")`:

```py
def savefile():
    # return the selected file object
    return asksaveasfile(defaultextension='*.jpg', filetypes=[
        ("All types", '.*'),
        ("JPG File", ".jpg")
    ], mode="wb")  # must use binary mode for image data

# Generate QR Code
def make():
    qr_codename = savefile()
    if qr_codename:
        qr_code = qrcode.make(link_entry.get())
        qr_code.save(qr_codename)
```